# Samba: permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I have a server with a host and a Virtualbox VM.
The host is running CentOS 7 and it is updated. Indeed the VM is running CentOS 5 and I know this OS is not supported by several years but I can't update it now.

The alert of the problem is too generic and it's shown when I try to mount on the VM the samba folder that is living on the host:

> mount error 13 = permission denied

I just followed this guide: [Install and configure samba CentOS 7](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-samba-on-centos-7/)

Samba version:
Host -> samba 5
VM -> samba 3

I tried:
Disabling firewalld and SELinux
Using NFS
Change password of users and use several users

But all this got nothing changed.

Hope y'all got tips and solutions for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the samba conf?

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan 
[private]
        comment = Privata
        path = /private
        read list = user2
        valid users = user1 user2
        write list = user1

This is the part of smb.conf in which I declare the samba folder I want to share with just some users.